# XNA multi class collision

Tags: class, xna, collision-detection

I am trying to make the enemy spawning / movement system for a side scrolling game.
What is supposed to happen is the enemies are to spawn and move right until they collide with a specific object then they will travel in the opposite direction.

I have done research and asked question to get me this far:
I have made an enemy class and then made a list that can add more enemies and set their individual spawning positions. Then I have made an `EnemyBlock` class so I can set where the various collision objects will be (In this case they are just brick squares).

I am having some trouble
A. In making the enemies turn around when they leave the game screen.
And B. writing collision code for the enemies and enemyblocks as when I try and write collision code in the `Game1.cs Update` section under `foreach (Enemy enemy in enemies)` it doesn't pick the the enemyblock's rectangle. If that makes sense. Im sorry but I am pretty new to XNA code.

Game1.cs code

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    public Rectangle bounds;

    List<Enemy> Enemies = new List<Enemy>();
    List<EnemyBlock> Blocks = new List<EnemyBlock>();

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }


    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

        base.Initialize();
    }


    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        Blocks.Add(new EnemyBlock(Content.Load<Texture2D>("02Brick"), new Vector2(50, 100)));
        Enemies.Add(new Enemy(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Mario_Sprite"), new Vector2(100, 100), new Vector2(1, 0)));
        Blocks.Add(new EnemyBlock(Content.Load<Texture2D>("02Brick"), new Vector2(500, 100)));
        Blocks.Add(new EnemyBlock(Content.Load<Texture2D>("02Brick"), new Vector2(50, 200)));
        Enemies.Add(new Enemy(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Mario_Sprite"), new Vector2(100, 200), new Vector2(1, 0)));
        Blocks.Add(new EnemyBlock(Content.Load<Texture2D>("02Brick"), new Vector2(400, 200)));

        foreach (Enemy enemy in Enemies)
        {
           enemy.bounds = new Rectangle((int)(enemy.position.X - enemy.texture.Width), (int)(enemy.position.Y - enemy.texture.Height), enemy.texture.Width, enemy.texture.Height);
        }
        foreach (EnemyBlock block in Blocks)
        {
            block.bounds = new Rectangle((int)(block.position.X - block.texture.Width), (int)(block.position.Y - block.texture.Height), block.texture.Width, block.texture.Height);
        }

    }


    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }


    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        foreach (Enemy enemy in Enemies)
        {
            if (!GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds.Contains(enemy.bounds))
            {
                enemy.velocity = -enemy.velocity;
                enemy.position += enemy.velocity;

            }

            else
            {

                enemy.position += enemy.velocity;

            }
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }


    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        foreach (Enemy enemy in Enemies)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(enemy.texture, enemy.position, Color.White);
        }
        foreach (EnemyBlock block in Blocks)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(block.texture, block.position, Color.White);
        }
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
}
```

Enemy class code

```
class Enemy
  {
      public Texture2D texture;
      public Rectangle bounds;
      public Vector2 position;
      public Vector2 velocity;

      public Enemy(Texture2D Texture, Vector2 Position, Vector2 Velocity)
      {
          texture = Texture;
          position = Position;
          velocity = Velocity;
      }
  }
```

EnemyBlock class code

```
class EnemyBlock
{
    public Texture2D texture;
    public Rectangle bounds;
    public Vector2 position;

    public EnemyBlock(Texture2D Texture, Vector2 Position)
    {
        texture = Texture;
        position = Position;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to be very well structured and organized. Makes it a lot easier to be able to find any of these problems your having so thanks and keep your code organized. It's a good habit and it makes larger projects much easier.

Anyways I think I might have the answer to your problem.

The reason your rectangles aren't being picked up is because you are initializing the rectangles for your enemies and blocks in your load content method.

This is fine except that you don't appear to update the position of the rectangles. You update the velocity and position of the enemies and blocks though you check for collision with the bounding rectangles.

This means that your enemies will be able to move off screen and through objects because your the draw position has moved but the rectangle hasn't meaning it won't detect the collision.

I believe other problem is with specifying the rectangle position. I believe your code maybe a bit off but if it works fine then leave it. But if the collision detection is a little off then try the following. Your code

```
enemy.bounds = new Rectangle((int)(enemy.position.X - enemy.texture.Width), (int)(enemy.position.Y - enemy.texture.Height), enemy.texture.Width, enemy.texture.Height);
```

should look like

```
enemy.bounds = new Rectangle(enemy.position.X, enemy.position.Y, enemy.texture.Width, enemy.texture.Height);
```

based on how you are drawing your images.

The constructor of the rectangle specifies the top left corner's x, y position and the width/height of the rectangle. Rectangle r = new Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200) creates a rectangle at 100, 100 and 200 wide and 200 tall.

This will match up with how you draw your enemies and blocks.

And lastly the collision code is fairly simple:

```
foreach(Enemy enemy in Enemies)
{
  foreach(EnemyBlock block in Blocks)
  {
    if(enemy.bounds.Contains(block.bounds))
    {
      //what to do on collision
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this is all correct and helps.

Comment: You, Mr Cumming, are a life saver. Thank you so much. I have been experimenting all night different ways to get the code to work. Making new classes, new lists, new projects! 
And I do like to keep my code neat for this exact reason. So I can go and fix things up and find them easily.
The new code works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not proficient on XNA, anyway,
try removing negation, because the code looks like it will always reverse the velocity while not on viewport's edge

```
 if (GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds.Contains(enemy.bounds))
 {
     enemy.velocity *= -1;
 }
     enemy.position += enemy.velocity;
```

with this, the enemy velocity will reverse only when it reaches the boundary.
No need to put an else statement since the enemy will always be moving.

As for the collision with enemy blocks, here is a good tutorial from MSDN on making 2D side scrolling games like mario. [CLICK HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd254918.aspx)

in the tutorial everything is treated as a tile object on 2d array map and on update, it checks against a tile of the array where the enemy is currently standing (enemy's position)